# Auto-Resize image through a hierarchy of elements to top element that specifies height

Tags: html, css

I know that I can auto-resize an image by making it `max-width:100%, max-height:100%` when the immediate parent specifies a height. This is shown in Example 2. But I need to auto-resize when it is nested in a hierarchy of elements, where some ancestor specifies a height. In Example 1, because it's not immediately under a height-specifying ancestor, the `height:45px` is not observed. Any quick solutions?

```css
img {
   max-height: 100%;
   max-width: 100%;
}

.container1 {
   height: 45px;
}

.container2 {
   height: 45px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container1">
   <div class="header">
      <a href='#'>
         <img src='https://cdn.sstatic.net/Img/teams/teams-illo-free-sidebar-promo.svg' />
      </a>
   </div>
</div>

<br/><br/><br/><br/>

<div class="container2">
    <img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Img/teams/teams-illo-free-sidebar-promo.svg" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the intermediate elements to 100% height. This prevents them growing (and overflowing their container) to accommodate their large descendant image.

```css
.container1, .container2 {
  height: 45px;
}

.container1 .header, .container1 .header>a, img {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container1">
   <div class="header">
      <a href='#'>
         <img src='https://cdn.sstatic.net/Img/teams/teams-illo-free-sidebar-promo.svg' />
      </a>
   </div>
</div>

<br/><br/><br/><br/>

<div class="container2">
    <img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Img/teams/teams-illo-free-sidebar-promo.svg" />
</div>
```